# Scaling performance across multi GPUs

Tags: tensorflow

I've been running CIFAR 10 model in the tensorflow tutorials to train across multiple GPUs.

Source:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.8/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py

GPUs:
NVIDIA 8 * M40

Configuration:
Tensorflow 0.8.0
, CUDA 7.5, cuDNN 4

The result of training performance was not scalable than expected. the pattern of graph looks like Amdahl's Law.

[the chart of scaling performance across multi GPUs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PG5XG.jpg)

Is it normal? If it is, What do you see as the main cause of that?

Comment: What's your GPU utilization like?

Comment: IMHO it's not normal, "examples per second" should scale linearly if you don't have bottlenecks.

Comment: Tensorflow Training : 
2016-04-22 12:45:19.902857: step 360, loss = 4.08 (3166.4 examples/sec; 0.040 sec/batch)

CPU Utilization: 
top - 12:47:45 up 6 days, 20:22,  2 users,  load average: 31.18, 17.92, 7.67
Tasks: 346 total,   1 running, 345 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 55.3 us, 23.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 21.1 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.2 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem : 65679412 total, 46795768 free,  7339948 used, 11543696 buff/cache
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 free,        0 used. 55707412 avail Mem

Comment: GPU Utilization : 

Tesla M40           On   | 0000:08:00.0     Off |                  Off |
P0    74W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     15%      
P0    67W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     21%      
P0    67W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     22%      
P0    68W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     25%      
P0    66W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     20%      
P0    81W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     13%      
P0    67W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     19%      
P0    70W / 250W |  11769MiB / 12287MiB |     14%

Comment: For 8 GPUs running, individual GPU utilization is 15~20%, CPU utilization is 56%
For 4 GPUs running, individual GPU utilization is 27~30%%, CPU utilization is 48%
For 2 GPUs running, individual GPU utilization is 35~40%, CPU utilization is 35%
For 8 GPUs running, the GPU utilization is 47%, CPU utilization is 23%

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the GPU utilization as high as you can (>80%). Most likely data from the disk is not delivered fast enough, so the GPUs are idle most of the time.